Почему считывание идёт с помпы (подключённая к реле), а не с датчика расхода воды?
Проблема в том, что считывание идёт с помпы (подключённая к реле), а не с датчика расхода воды.
Код проблемной части:
uint8_t  pinSensor = 2;                                     // Определяем номер вывода Arduino, к которому подключён датчик расхода воды.
//
float    varQ;                                              // Объявляем переменную для хранения рассчитанной скорости потока воды (л/с).
float    varV;                                              // Объявляем переменную для хранения рассчитанного объема воды (л).
const int pompa = 8;                                        // помпа подключённая через реле на8 контакте
void setup() {                                              
  Serial.begin(9600);                                       // Инициируем передачу данных в монитор последовательного порта.
  pinMode(pinSensor, INPUT);                                // Конфигурируем вывод к которому подключён датчик, как вход.
  varQ = 0; varV = 0;                                       // Обнуляем все переменные.
}                                                           

void loop() {
  pinMode(pompa, OUTPUT);
  varQ = 0;                                                 // Сбрасываем скорость потока воды.
  uint32_t varL  = pulseIn(pinSensor, HIGH, 200000);        // Считываем длительность импульса, но не дольше 0,2 сек.
  if ( varL ) {                                             // Если длительность импульса считана, то ...
    float varT = 2.0 * (float)varL / 1000000;               // Определяем период следования импульсов в сек.
    float varF = 1 / varT;                                  // Определяем частоту следования импульсов в Гц.
    varQ = varF / 450.0f;                                   // Определяем скорость потока воды л/с.
    varV += varQ * varT;                                    // Определяем объем воды л.
  }                                                         //
  //  Выводим рассчитанные данные:                          //
  Serial.println((String) "Объем " + varV + "л, скорость " + (varQ * 60.0f) + "л/м.");
  digitalWrite(pompa, LOW);                                 // Включение помпы через реле
}

Подключение у меня на ардуино уно на словах:
5v - COM и VCC на реле и датчик расхода (красный провод)
GND - к реле на GND, помпе (чёрный провод) и к датчику расхода воды (чёрный провод)
Контакт 8 - К реле на IN
Контакт 2 - к датчику расхода воды (жёлтый провод)
NO на реле - к плюсу помпы (красный провод).

А какая ошибка возникает? Что делается по факту и как вы ожидаете, чтобы было?

Я не понял, вы пишите, что у вас идет считывание с помпы.. но если посмотреть, то у вас на помпу подается сигнал, но никак не считывание - pinMode(pompa, OUTPUT);

Здравствуйте! Извините что плохо разъяснил тему, но при включение помпы, начинает расти значение датчика расходы воды, хотя жидкость внутри него не проводится. Возможно из-за «pulsein()”, но есть шанс что у меня неправильное подключение (если что все компоненты подключены как я писал).

Ничего не понятно но очень интересно, что за датчик используется? какой сигнал он выдает? почему вы ожидаете импульс какой то длинны?)

я конечно не эксперт, но мне кажется, что может быть лучше поменять название перемнных т.к. varL varQ и тп не самое информативное решение

А если убрать пока вообще отсюда помпу и упростить задачу до считывания расхода с датчика расхода. Вот тут что-то подобно есть, а потом уже добавить помпу: https://wiki.iarduino.ru/page/sensor-water-flow/

Вывод с включённым реле:
Объем 1.18л, скорость 1.90л/м.
Объем 1.18л, скорость 1.90л/м.
Объем 1.18л, скорость 7.59л/м.
Объем 1.18л, скорость 3.79л/м.
Объем 1.18л, скорость 7.59л/м.
Объем 1.19л, скорость 7.59л/м.
Объем 1.19л, скорость 3.79л/м.
Объем 1.19л, скорость 22222.22л/м.
Объем 1.19л, скорость 0.00л/м.
Объем 1.19л, скорость 4.58л/м.
Если его выключить, то показания останутся (а не сбросятся, но скорость воды начнёт снижаться) , а показания с датчика расхода воды будут браться с него.

Использую: реле от smartelement, датчик расхода воды YF-S401. Код на датчик расхода воды брал с сайта https://wiki.iarduino.ru/page/sensor-water-flow/.

Проблема была в том, что у меня было неправильно подключено реле.
